# If I imported a class, should I still prepend that class name to its methods when they're used in a different class?

Tags: vb.net, oop, import, convention

I work with a codebase where there are many classes with thousands of lines of code. I've noticed inconsistencies in style concerning prepending class names when using their methods and I'm trying to figure out the previous developer's reasoning. If we

```
import GeneralCode
```

in Class A, is it bad practice to write

```
GeneralCode.DoSomething()
```

in Class A since we already imported it (instead of simply using `DoSomething()`)? I would think so, but I suppose it's also nice to know which methods come from which classes at a glance, since Class A imports many classes and uses methods from several of them.

**EDIT**: This is for VB.NET, not Java (sorry for the wrong tag, rough morning). I am new to VB.NET but `GeneralCode` and `DoSomething()` are not declared as static, neither is the import in Class A.

Might be something to do with VB.NET, but `DoSomething()` can indeed be used with or without prepending `GeneralCode`.

Comment: If you're writing the class name before calling the method, it's a static method. They're different to instance methods. If you don't already know the difference, have a look online. If you don't like writing the class name for static methods, you can do a `static import`.

Comment: You should only do it if neccessary, that is if it is a static method of another class. If it is a static method of your own class then you do not need it, thus I would leave it. The later is opinion based, however the most strict style configurations I worked with want me to leave it.

Comment: Sorry, I put the java tag thinking about OOP (since I am used to java), instead of vb.net which is the actual case I am working with (long tiring morning). I've updated the question with additional information.

Answer (score 0):

A method need to be prefixed with

1. The class name if it's a static method.
2. The name of the instance when it's not a static method.

Unless you are calling a method from your own class.

Comment: Turns out the question is VB.Net, not Java. Bad tagging.